# Connect / Weld Vertices / Edge

Tags: vertices

I dont need this vertices and/or edge.
What is the best way to get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, for those looking for the `Weld Edges into Faces` tool, [it's here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#weld-edges-into-faces) (though the documentation is not very helpful).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the edge with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*.

[image]